# Home and desktop got merged in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

Home and Desktop got merged in my system. Means whatever I save in home gets automatically save on Desktop and if I delete anything from the desktop it gets deleted from home as well.

How can I get rid from this?

Comment: Desktop is one of the directories inside Home.

Comment: Yes it is but all the contents in home are also shown in desktop. I dont want to show them in desktop but it is showing so how ca I solve this

Comment: What environment are you using?

Comment: I am using Gnome

Comment: What is the output of command `gsettings get org.gnome.nautilus.preferences desktop-is-home-dir` run in a terminal?

Comment: I got the following output "No such key 'desktop-is-home-dir'"

Comment: what is the output of `xdg-user-dir DESKTOP` ?

Comment: It is "/home/charu/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from here: http://johnpoelstra.com/gnome-desktop-full-of-files-directories/

1.Open Nautilus

2. Press Ctrl+H to show hidden files.
3. Got to the .config directory.
4. Open the file ''user-dirs.dirs''
5. Find the line and make sure it reads as follows: XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop" .
6. Save changes and exit editor.

I have not been able to test it myself but hoping to solve your problem.

Answer (score -2):

Open terminal, go to home folder and do `ls -al`. This will show you if Desktop has somehow become symlink to home. If so, just delete Desktop folder in file manager and recreate it.

Comment: When I ran the above command I got 
"drwxrwxr-x  8 charu charu 4096 Sep 24 22:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 47 charu charu 4096 Jan 29 19:42 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 charu charu 4096 Sep 23 13:36 cache
drwxrwxr-x  2 charu charu 4096 Sep 24 22:06 database
drwxrwxr-x  3 charu charu 4096 Sep 24 11:42 incoming
drwxrwxr-x  2 charu charu 4096 Sep 23 13:34 logs
drwxrwxr-x  3 charu charu 4096 Sep 23 13:34 templates
drwxrwxr-x 20 charu charu 4096 Sep 24 22:00 tmp"
I am unable to find symlink for Desktop. What should be done to solve this?

Comment: Did you run it in your home folder? Surely? Did you delete all the standard foilders like Video, Music, so on? Anyway, try to do `mkdir /home/(yourusername)/Desktop`

Comment: Problem remains same even after doing so